# Can the recently read module show multiple nodes?

Tags: 7

I am working with the recently read module and it is only showing the last node visited. I want it to show the last 5 nodes visited and that seems like what the module is supposed to do. I have session API enabled so that I can have this available for anonymous users as well. Does anyone know why it is only displaying a single node?

Answer (score 0):

From the content of your question, I have the impression that you misunderstand what the [Recently Read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read) module is about. More specifically (from its project page): it keeps track of "*... the history of recently read content (nodes) both to anonymous and authenticated users ...*".

Anonymous users is a special case, but for logged in users each user has his/her own "history".

[Issue #1973526](https://www.drupal.org/node/1973526) also confirms that, here is part of what that says:

> Since you don't want your database getting forever more massive for no good reason (it is likely you will only ever be showing the last 5 or 10) it would be good to have an option to **limit the maximum number of entries in the recently read table for each user**.
>
> For example I can set it to 5 and the database would only ever have 5 entries per user at most.

It would be interesting to know, for your environment, how many nodes (more then one?) you visited with the user you are logged in with (if you are logged in). To remove any doubt about that, consider editing your question by adding some scenarios (+ results you get) like "user 1 visited node a, b and c; user 2 visited b, p, q, r, s, z, ..."; anonymous user visited k, l , m ..."

Comment: I have the view set to display 5 items. I am logged in to my account on the site and visit 5 separate nodes. Only 1 displays in the recently read block however. That's the problem I'm having.

Comment: Can you add a screenprint to your quetion conaining the typical Views UI screen with all the fields, filter(s), etc included for that view?